# PHP Email form bold for headings on email message items

Tags: php, email

I have a php form that sends an email, however I would like to put the headings of each section in bold but can't seem to get it to work from everywhere I've searched.

The form:

```
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($firstlastname)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Property Type: ".clean_string($ptype)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "From Address: ".clean_string($faddress)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "To Address: ".clean_string($taddress)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Moving Items Description: ".clean_string($itemsdescription)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Dissasembling Requirements: ".clean_string($disassemble)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Packaging Requirements: ".clean_string($packaging)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Preferred Date and Time: ".clean_string($dateandtime)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Property Access: ".clean_string($paccess)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Stair Count: ".clean_string($staircount)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n\n";

// create email headers
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

I've tried adding the bold and strong tags to the headings;

```
$email_message .= "<b>Name:</b> ".clean_string($firstlastname)."\n\n";
```

Still not working, including setting it outside of the heading of the text.

Edit: this is the full form

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Form Submission";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['firstlastname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['ptype']) ||
        !isset($_POST['faddress']) ||   
        !isset($_POST['taddress']) ||
        !isset($_POST['itemsdescription']) ||   
        !isset($_POST['disassemble']) ||        
        !isset($_POST['packaging']) ||  
        !isset($_POST['dateandtime']) ||        
        !isset($_POST['paccess']) ||
        !isset($_POST['staircount']) ||     
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $firstlastname = $_POST['firstlastname']; 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; 
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; 
    $ptype = $_POST['ptype']; 
    $faddress = $_POST['faddress']; 
    $taddress = $_POST['taddress']; 
    $itemsdescription = $_POST['itemsdescription']; 
    $disassemble = $_POST['disassemble']; 
    $packaging = $_POST['packaging']; 
    $dateandtime = $_POST['dateandtime']; 
    $paccess = $_POST['paccess']; 
    $staircount = $_POST['staircount']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$firstlastname)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }


  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($firstlastname)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Property Type: ".clean_string($ptype)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "From Address: ".clean_string($faddress)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "To Address: ".clean_string($taddress)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Moving Items Description: ".clean_string($itemsdescription)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Dissasembling Requirements: ".clean_string($disassemble)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Packaging Requirements: ".clean_string($packaging)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Preferred Date and Time: ".clean_string($dateandtime)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Property Access: ".clean_string($paccess)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Stair Count: ".clean_string($staircount)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n\n";

// create email headers
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

<script>window.location.replace("index.html");</script>

<?php



}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try `<p style='font-weight:600'>Name:</p>`

Comment: It doesn't matter what tags I use it shows up in the email, the paragraph tag included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a dot to append more headers. This overwrites your Content-Type and that is why it is parsing the email as text and not has HTML

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

Comment: I tried it with adding the dots and I get a parse error, removing the dots and it doesn't parse as html :S I was so hopeful it was just that small error!

Comment: It worked that time!! I tried exactly that the first time and it didn't work but I tried it again and Bam it worked! Thank you kindly sir!

Comment: Glad you got solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

```
 $email_message .= "<strong>Name:</strong>  ".clean_string($firstlastname)."\n\n";
```

or

```
 $email_message .= "<b>Name:</b>  ".clean_string($firstlastname)."\n\n";
```

or

```
 $email_message .= "<p style="font-weight: bold;">Name:</b>  ".clean_string($firstlastname)."\n\n";
```

Comment: All of the tags show up as text in the email rather than tags :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Use PHP Mailer plugin.

Download Plugin in following link:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases/tag/v5.2.26    

$mail_message='Dear '.$row[0]['branch_name'].','. "\r\n";
                $mail_message.='Thanks for contacting regarding to forgot password,<br> Your <b>Password</b> is <b>'.$passwordplain.'</b>'."\r\n";
                $mail_message.='<br>Please Update your password.';
                $mail_message.='<br>Thanks & Regards';
                $mail_message.='<br>Test group of company';

                date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
                require FCPATH.'application/libraries/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                // $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
                $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
                $mail->Host = "(HOST SERVER)";
                $mail->Port = 465;
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
                $mail->Username = "(USERNAME)";    
                $mail->Password = "(PASSWORD)";
                $mail->setFrom('(FROM MAIL ADDRESS)', 'Test group of company');
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->addAddress($email);
                $mail->Subject = 'New password for login';
                $mail->Body    = $mail_message;

                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    $data['message_display'] = 'Failed to send password, please try again!';
                    $this->load->view('branch/forgotPassword', $data);
                } else {
                    $data['message_display'] = 'Password sent to your email!';
                    $this->load->view('branch/forgotPassword', $data);
                }
```

Comment: Is this an answer to another question? I'm not seeing the relevance to my question here?